# Python. Определение, запущена ли программа от имени администратора

Tags: python, администрирование

Как удобней и легче всего проверить, запущена ли программа от имени администратора?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Cross-platform way to check admin rights in a Python script under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026431/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import ctypes

def is_admin():
    try:
        return os.getuid() == 0
    except AttributeError:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
```

Comment: желательно ссылку на [скопированное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026626/4279) указывать.

Comment: @jfs да я просто не помню откуда оно у меня в скрипте четырёхлетней давности.

Comment: @jfs, [больше 3к совпадений по IsUserAnAdmin для питона](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=%22IsUserAnAdmin%28%29%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)